# I cant force to establish a value in a label and at the same time a method is executed

Tags: python, tkinter

how are you, I am writing to ask you how I can do it, currently I have a clock with a countdown (10 minutes) in the main window, on the other screen (toplevel) I have another clock with a countdown but of 24 seconds, everything is perfect but The only thing that I cannot solve is: how to make it so that when I press the button (reset 24 seconds) it goes back to 24 and that everything continues to work normally, since what it does is for a moment it puts me at 24 seconds and then it returns where was the countdown at the time of pressing the reset button.

```
 def countdown(self,minutos,segundos,posesion):

            if self.is_running:       
                
                minutos_final=int(minutos)
                segundos_final=int(segundos)             
                posesion_final=int(posesion)    

                self.text_minutos.set(f"{minutos_final:02d}")
                self.text_segundos.set(f"{segundos_final:02d}")    
                self.text_segundos_posesion.set(posesion_final)
                
                if segundos_final > 0:
        
                    self.after_id =self.tablero_principal.after(1000,self.countdown,minutos_final,segundos_final -1,posesion_final-1)

                if segundos_final ==0 and minutos_final>0:                  
                   
                    segundos_final=60
                    self.after_id =self.tablero_principal.after(1000, self.countdown,minutos_final-1, segundos_final-1,posesion_final-1)


    def iniciar(self):

            if not self.is_running:  ## avoid 2 button pushes
                self.is_running=True

                
                if self.text_segundos_posesion.get()=="0":
                
                    self.countdown(self.text_minutos.get(),self.text_segundos.get(),24)  

 
                elif self.text_minutos.get()=="00" and self.text_segundos.get()=="00":

                    self.countdown(self.text_minutos_fijos,self.text_segundos_fijos,24)  

                    self.text_cuarto.set(str(int(self.text_cuarto.get()) + 1))     

                else:

                    self.countdown(self.text_minutos.get(),self.text_segundos.get(),self.text_segundos_posesion.get())     
                 

    def parar(self):

        self.is_running = False             
        self.tablero_principal.after_cancel(self.after_id)

    def forzar_24(self): #HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        
        self.tablero_principal.after_cancel(self.after_id)
        self.text_segundos_posesion.set("24")

        self.iniciar()
```

[screen of the 2 windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfyIw.png)

Comment: Right now what happens is there is a scheduled call to `countdown` and while the timer for that is ticking, you call `ext_segundos_posesion.set("24")`. What you should do is cancel the `.after` call. Something like: `self.after_id = self.tablero_principal.after(...)` and then in `parar` call `self.tablero_principal.after_cancel(self.after_id)`.

Comment: hello thanks Thelizzard for answering, I edited what you put but the initial clock of 24 does not stop, the 2 countdowns of 24 continue to work. pd: i update the code

Comment: I was able to stop the method but to start it back with 24 seconds, do I have to create another method?